# Get function callers

Tags: php, function, arguments, line

I'm trying to get all function callers and know if the callers are calling function with arguments, I'm trying this because with PHP 7.1 version, if the caller don't have same arguments that function definition,fatal error is fired.

File 1.php

Example:

```
  function a($y, $x, $r){
     echo "hello world";
   }

a("watermelon","lemon", "orange" );
```

File 2.php

```
a("apple", "banana");
```

And now the idea would be a function to get where a() is called and where is not called with all necessary arguments

Exists any native function or any tool to do this? 
I use get_defined_functions() to get all functions list and I put into array , maybe exists something similar to get where each function is called in the project?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I suppose you can only search your project and fix codes manually.

Comment: Well, I'm developing a script to do this atumatically, manually is not an option to a 2 million code lines project :|